# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate ContextMenu not Opening

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview that is loading based on datatype.  If the HierarchicalDataTemplates are nested like below the cMenuBSTool ContextMenu will display on the first child InventoryBSVM but not on any InventoryBSVM children of the first child InventoryBSVM:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type v:ServiceGWDVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ToolSelector}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ServiceStyle}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource cMenuServiceGWD}"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type v:InventoryBSVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ToolSelector}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource ToolStyle}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource cMenuBSTool}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

If I place the InventoryBSVM HierarchicalDataTemplate outside of the ServiceGWDVM HierarchicalDataTemplate the cMenuBSTool ContextMenu will not display for any InventoryBSVM Nodes.  The number of InventoryBSVM children of other InventoryBSVM is not known in advance.  The ContextMenu is very simple as can be seen below:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cMenuBSTool">
    <MenuItem Header="Delete Tool" Command="{Binding CmdDelete}">
        <MenuItem.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.Click"/>
        </MenuItem.Triggers>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Create Tool" Command="{Binding CmdCreate}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource wizCreateBS}">
        <MenuItem.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.Click"/>
        </MenuItem.Triggers>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

I hope there is something simple that I am missing.  I have spent two days on this now and am stuck.  This is my first post on Stack Overflow and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the output window? Have you tried snooping to see if the item has the context menu or not? Why do you have an `ItemTemplateSelector` when you already have an `ItemTemplate` defined? Why do you have an empty `EventTrigger` on your menu items?

Comment: No errors in the output window.  I was moving the InventoryBSVM HierarchicalDataTemplate around to see if I could get it to work at all.  That is the reason for ItemTemplateSelector and HiearchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate.  I removed the EventTrigger, thanks.  It wasn't doing anything.  Can you recommend a "snooper"?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2015, you can use the Live Visual Tree. Otherwise I usually use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). Btw I tested your code in an otherwise empty project (with my own VM classes, since I don't know what yours look like), removing the `ItemTemplateSelector` and the `EventTrigger` and it works fine.

Comment: I'll try Snoop and see what I find.  Thanks.